# Repeat image gradient on background image

Tags: android, image, gradient

I am downloading image from server and setting it to background. but i need to assign repeat image gradient to that background image and i have some text which i need to show on top of that.

Here is my code which are use to download image from server and setting it to background.

```
Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage(imageUrl);
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
bitmapDrawable.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.RIGHT);
//Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
myLinearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

I create one layerlist which i need to show on that top of background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="500"
            android:startColor="#17568A"
            android:endColor="#494C4F" />  

    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/gradient_dish"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

But i already assigning server image to layout background so not able to assign this xml file in background.

I have one image "gradient_dish" which i want make repeat and want to show with background image.

How can i do this? please provide me some reference or link.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can't you simply create a `LayerDrawable` in code from the `BitmapDrawable` fetched from the web + the layers from the xml drawable that you posted and use that as the background?

Comment: do you have any reference code for this?

Comment: Have a look at this https://gist.github.com/luksprog/5696975

Comment: can you post your answer... you solve my problem so i just want assign this bounty to you..... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the image you retrieve from the web you can construct the desired drawable, also adding the drawables from the xml file you posted. You could use the method below:

```
public Drawable createBackground(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[3];
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
    bitmapDrawable.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT);
    layers[0] = bitmapDrawable;
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    gd.setGradientRadius(500);
    gd.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.RADIAL_GRADIENT);
    gd.setColors(new int[] { Color.parseColor("#17568A"),
            Color.parseColor("#494C4F") });
    layers[1] = gd;
    BitmapDrawable lastBitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.id.gradient_dish);
    lastBitmapDrawable.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);
    layers[2] = lastBitmapDrawable;
    LayerDrawable bck = new LayerDrawable(layers);
    return bck;
}
```

Then you would simply do:

```
Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage(imageUrl);
myLinearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(createBackground(bitmap));
```

Comment: Can you do one favor. It's working on emulator but not on real device... how?  Thanks...

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil It doesn't work in which way(is incomplete, the image doesn't appear at all)? Also, on which device did you tested it and with what api level(have you tried testing on other devices also)?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the image as a background to a simple View that spans the whole screen and then place the rest of your layout 'on top' of that and make your gradient semi-transparent (resp. start from a non-transparent color and go to a semi- or completely transparent color).
This way the image will shine through true as desired.